# How to extract different sizes of an icon from favicon.ico file?

Tags: php, png, favicon, extract

I want to extract different sizes (if available) from favicon.ico file and save each to separate .png files (e.g. favicon16.png, favicon32.png etc.) using PHP. How to achieve that?

Comment: IcoFX may be helpful though by no means is this a programming approach, nor am I affiliated with the developer of this program. (http://icofx.ro/)

Answer (score 2):

[A class](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/9705.html) to extract icons from a .ico file as PNG files

I know not everybody likes phpclasses.org; but if it works, use it